# I have an error when I add new information in my Hive box Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

First I create a new patient with name, first name ...
it is possible to add an unlimited number of notes per patient so I use a list in the patient list called ListNote

so each time I add a note I modify the box of the patient in question

my problem is that I can't modify the box of the patient

I get an error when I try to add a new data to my boxpatient.
This new data is added to another list called ListNote which is in my patient list

**ERR Hive**

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: ListNote. Did you forget to register an adapter?
#0      BinaryWriterImpl.write
package:hive/…/binary/binary_writer_impl.dart:338
#1      BinaryWriterImpl.writeList
package:hive/…/binary/binary_writer_impl.dart:223
#2      BinaryWriterImpl._writeList
package:hive/…/binary/binary_writer_impl.dart:390
#3      BinaryWriterImpl.write
package:hive/…/binary/binary_writer_impl.dart:329
#4      PatientsAdapter.write
package:medicalnote/models/listpatient.g.dart:50
#5      BinaryWriterImpl.write
package:hive/…/binary/binary_writer_impl.dart:344
#6      BinaryWriterImpl.writeFrame
package:hive/…/binary/binary_writer_impl.dart:282
#7      StorageBackendVm.writeFrames.<anonymous closure>
package:hive/…/vm/storage_backend_vm.dart:128
#8      ReadWriteSync.syncWrite.<anonymous closure>
package:hive/…/vm/read_write_sync.dart:26
<asynchronous suspen<…>
```

**Here is my model**

```dart
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

part 'listpatient.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Patients {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String? name;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String? firstname;

  @HiveField(3)
  final String? dateofbirth;

  @HiveField(4)
  final String? email;

  @HiveField(5)
  final String? numero;

  @HiveField(6)
  final DateTime? date;

  @HiveField(7)
  final int? id;

  @HiveField(8)
  final List<ListNote>? listOfNotes;

  const Patients({
    this.name,
    this.firstname,
    this.dateofbirth,
    this.email,
    this.numero,
    this.date,
    this.id,
    this.listOfNotes,
  });
}

@HiveType(typeId: 10)
class ListNote {
  @HiveField(1)
  final String? title;

  @HiveField(2)
  final String? note;

  @HiveField(3)
  final String? conclusion;

  ListNote({
    this.title,
    this.note,
    this.conclusion,
  });
}
```

**My model generate**

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'listpatient.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class PatientsAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Patients> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  Patients read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return Patients(
      name: fields[0] as String?,
      firstname: fields[1] as String?,
      dateofbirth: fields[3] as String?,
      email: fields[4] as String?,
      numero: fields[5] as String?,
      date: fields[6] as DateTime?,
      id: fields[7] as int?,
      listOfNotes: (fields[8] as List?)?.cast<ListNote>(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Patients obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(8)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.name)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.firstname)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.dateofbirth)
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..write(obj.email)
      ..writeByte(5)
      ..write(obj.numero)
      ..writeByte(6)
      ..write(obj.date)
      ..writeByte(7)
      ..write(obj.id)
      ..writeByte(8)
      ..write(obj.listOfNotes);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is PatientsAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}

class ListNoteAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ListNote> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  ListNote read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return ListNote(
      title: fields[1] as String?,
      note: fields[2] as String?,
      conclusion: fields[3] as String?,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, ListNote obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.title)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.note)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.conclusion);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ListNoteAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

**Here is how I add a new note to my box**

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    boxPatient = Hive.box('Patient');
  }

  void _addNote(String newtitle, String newnote, String newconclusion) {
    final newNOTE = Patients(
      listOfNotes: [
        ListNote(title: newtitle, note: newnote, conclusion: newconclusion)
      ],
    );
    boxPatient.add(newNOTE);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

**Thanks a lot for your help :)**

Comment: check your main method to register `PatientsAdapter`

Comment: void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(PatientsAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Patients>('Patient');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Everything is good (I think)

To add patients everything works I just have a problem when I add a note

Comment: I think you'll need to register ListNoteAdapter in main as well, if you haven't already.